# Angular2 httpbackend mocking REST request

Tags: rest, angular, mocking, backend, httpbackend

I'm strugling trying to run a simple example of backend mocking REST request in angular2. 
After a few days facing many issues getting the instance of "httpbackend" object i found these guidelines.

https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy/issues/1
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E

Install instructions

```
npm install httpbackend --save-dev
npm install angular-mocks --save-dev
```

Spec file

```
var HttpBackend = require('httpbackend');

browser.addMockModule('httpbackend', function() {
  angular.module('httpbackend', ['ngMockE2E']);
});

describe('HTTP backend REST methods', function() {
    var httpBackend;
    var result;

    beforeEach(function() {
        httpBackend = new HttpBackend(browser);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.clear();
    });

    it('should validate action when POST request', function() {
        browser.get('');  

        httpBackend.whenPOST('app/mock-data/post-action.json').respond(function(method, url, data) {
            return [200, data];
        });

        var buttons = [
            'button_A', 
            'button_B', 
            'button_C', 
            'button_9', 
            'button_5', 
            'button_7', 
            'button_6', 
            'base-keyboard-ok' 
        ];

        buttonsClick = function(j){
            var buttonKey = browser.driver.findElement(by.id(buttons[j]));
            buttonKey.click();
        }

        for(j=0; j<buttons.length; j++){
            buttonsClick(j);
        }

        browser.sleep(2000);

        result = element(by.binding('app/mock-data/post-action.json')); 
        expect(result.getText()).toEqual('ABC9576'); //That's the target i want to reach
    });

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.